# Efficient indexing from integers array

Tags: python, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a piece of code that requires selecting data from two different ndarrays for some operations. I want to implement a fast but memory-safe approach to achieve this. At the moment, I have something like this, where the indices are contained in two different ndarrays of integers:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

from time import time


def array_selection( A,B, indices_0, indices_1, number_iters ):
    
    for n in range( number_iters ):
        a_selection = A[ indices_0[:,0], :, :, :, indices_1[:,0], indices_1[:,1]   ]
        b_selection = B[ indices_0[:,1], :, :, :, indices_1[:,2], indices_1[:,3]   ]   
        #do something on a_selection, b_selection 
        

N       = 2000
n_sel   = 500
d1      = 7
d2      = 3

number_iters = 10

A       = np.random.rand(  d2, N, d1,d1,d2,d2  ) + 1j*np.random.rand(  d2, N, d1,d1,d2,d2  )
B       = np.random.rand(  d2, N, d1,d1,d2,d2  ) + 1j*np.random.rand(  d2, N, d1,d1,d2,d2  )


indices_0 = np.random.choice( [0,1,2], ( n_sel, 2 )   )
indices_1 = np.random.choice( np.arange(3), ( n_sel, 4 )   )

ts = time()
array_selection( A,B, indices_0, indices_1, number_iters )

print(time()-ts)
```

However, when timing this in the code, this seems to be highly inefficient, as it takes very long to allocate the 'a_selection' and 'b_selection' arrays. Note that these are inside a for loop  too, is there an efficient way to do this? Also, I would like to know if this implementation would benefit from a multi-core system where this is supposed to be running. For example, using Python's `multiprocessing pool` to divide the n_sel jobs into smaller jobs, would that make a huge difference? Any other alternatives?

Comment: You can vectorize your selection loop, by vectorizing I mean that you can use just Numpy functions without having a loop. But the way to vectorize depends on the way how you want to use data later in your code. Also as I see a/b selections in the loop don't depend on loop variable, it means that they can be done before loop, and inside loop you just use one single selection. If your usage code is not too large or too secret, you can share it an we'll think about optimizations.

Comment: Oh you are right, the indices for selection in this case do not depend on n, so I can make this multiple selection just once outside the "n" loop, thanks for pointing that out! I might upload a full version of the code once I have corrected this so that more optimizations can be thought.